# get widget instance

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

how to get class intance from widget instance.  in gwt, my widget is a private field of pojo class.   i able to get the widget using  instanceOfPojo.returnWidget(); method. May i know how to get instance class of the widget so that i can use for

```
   if( widget instanceof CustomWidgetClass) ?
```

--
Let me rephrase

let say ,  AbcClass extends Composite, we can check whether match with

```
if(widget instanceof AbcClass)  .
```

but let say we do not know the class AbcClass exist, but we can get instance of abcClass. with this instance of abcClass, how to use java to create similar class and we call it DefClass so that we can cast abcClass to it?

Comment: GWT supports instanceof - the condition in your question [if (widget instanceof CustomWidgetClass)] should work as expected. Can you be more specific about the problem you are having?

Comment: @Jason, yes i know gwt support instanceof,  the problem is my widget is not created with concrete class. it's inside instanceofPojo. so how to i use it compared with  if( widget instanceof instanceOfPojo.returnWidget()) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... so how to i use it compared with if( widget instanceof instanceOfPojo.returnWidget()) ?

<strike>I'm really having a hard time understanding what you are asking for. Are you trying to get a working equivalent of `widget instanceof instanceOfPojo.returnWidget()`, which doesn't work because `instanceof` only works with Class literals?</strike>

To see if the class of `instanceOfPojo.returnWidget()` is a superclass of `widget`'s class,  you could use [isAssignableFrom](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
instanceOfPojo.returnWidget().getClass().isAssignableFrom(widget.getClass());
```

To see if they are the exact same class:

```
instanceOfPojo.returnWidget().getClass() == widget.getClass()
```

<strike>If that's not what you mean, please try to clarify your question.</strike>

***Edit:*** OP has since clarified the question.

> ... we can get instance of abcClass.  with this instance of abcClass, how to use java to create similar class

To get an instance of a class and then create a similar class from it would require dynamically creating a class at run-time.  Its possible in Java to dynamically create a class, but I very much doubt you could do it in GWT client code. This is because GWT supports only a subset of Java and gets translated to Javascript.

> ... we call it DefClass so that we can cast abcClass to it?

Since the class of `abcClass` is the  ("unknown") class `AbcClass` and `AbcClass` derives directly from Composite, you won't be able to cast `abcClass` to this dynamic class `DefClass`.  `DefClass` is not part of `abcClass` inheritance hierarchy (`AbcClass` -> `Composite` -> `Widget` -> `UIObject` -> `Object`) and you can't change that inheritance hierarchy to include `DefClass` during runtime after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

If you got your widget is inside your POJO then I would recommend you to revisit your design. Maybe a factory would be a better design for what you are trying to do.

Comment: yes. can you elaborate more on how to use factory for this case.

Comment: is using generic help on this?

Comment: From what you described (Widgets inside POJOs), looks like you are trying to map specific custom widgets to the pojos. e.g. if POJO is of type A it should be represented with Widget A. If that is the case then you should define your widgets and have a factory class return the appropriate widget based on the POJO you pass to the factory  Check out the example here http://www.allapplabs.com/java_design_patterns/factory_pattern.htm